# C# Issue with using Methods

Tags: c#

I have been given an assignment to calculate hospital fees with different methods. I have figured out most of it , but I am stuck on one part. When I try to use a variable from another method the value doesn't seem to move over to the new method. what would be the proper way of going about this? I have issues with the CalcTotalCharges method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace hospitalBills
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int dayStayd = int.Parse(dayStay.Text);
            int medFee = int.Parse(medCharge.Text);
            int surgFee = int.Parse(surgCharges.Text);
            int labFee = int.Parse(labCharges.Text);
            int rhbFee = int.Parse(rhbCharges.Text);
            CalcStayCharge(dayStayd);
            CalcMiscCharges(medFee, surgFee, labFee, rhbFee);
            CalcTotalCharges(totalFee,stayCost);
            total.Text = totalCost.ToString();

        }
        public int CalcStayCharge(int dayStayd)
        {
            int stayCost = dayStayd * 350;
            return stayCost;
        }
        public int CalcMiscCharges(int medFee, int surgFee, int labFee, int rhbFee)
        {
            int totalFee = medFee + surgFee + labFee + rhbFee;
            return totalFee;
        }
        public int CalcTotalCharges(int totalFee, int stayCost)
        {
            int totalCost = totalFee + stayCost;
            return totalCost;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you are calling a method that returns a datatype for example `int` do the following `var someClacStayCharge = CalcStayCharge(dayStayd);` for example do the same for the other 2 methods.. you are returning an Int but never really capturing / assigning it to a local variable to be used within the scope of the `enter_Click` event if you want you could also replace the local variables and convert them to auto properties and store the int values there.. there are a few ways you can handle this.. but for now all you are doing is calling a method and returning something that's never captured

Comment: @Ben it's quite obvious to see what method is working but what the OP is expecting in regards to how to call the method is not working 
`CalcTotalCharges(totalFee,stayCost);
  total.Text = totalCost.ToString();`

Comment: @TacosaurusRex I would suggest that you do a google search on the following in regards to `void methods and methods that return a value` this would help you understand how to call methods that return a value in regards to capturing and assigning their value(s) [MSDN return C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

As @MethodMan states in his comment, your functions "work" but you need to capture the output in a variable in order to use them. See below for an example of how to do that.

```
private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int dayStayd = int.Parse(dayStay.Text);
    int medFee = int.Parse(medCharge.Text);
    int surgFee = int.Parse(surgCharges.Text);
    int labFee = int.Parse(labCharges.Text);
    int rhbFee = int.Parse(rhbCharges.Text);
    var stayCost = CalcStayCharge(dayStayd);
    var totalFee = CalcMiscCharges(medFee, surgFee, labFee, rhbFee);
    var totalCost = CalcTotalCharges(totalFee,stayCost);
    total.Text = totalCost.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I saw that immediately but wanted to give the OP an opportunity to think about how to assign return values to a variable +1